# create horizontal scrolling UIButton in iOS using UIScrollView in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, button, uiscrollview

I'm new to ios development now want give a horizontal scrolling button in my app i dont no wt is the correct method to do it can any pls tell how to make it

this is the code i have tried to create a uibutton horizontal pro grammatically but its now working its throughing a warning

> undeclared selector newView

i dont know wt i have to code in newview to make the button scroll im using more than four button i want all the buttons to be scroll in horizontal but i not able to make i have tried to create using one button

this is the code i have used in the view didload

```
   UIScrollView *scrollview =[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
     scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=YES;
     scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
     scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(newView:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [button setTitle:@"Excavations" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

   [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
   scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,960);
```

can any one pls tell me wt is the right way to make the horizontal scroll wheather i have use the uiscorllview and buttons in my storyboard and how to make into scroll the buttons

i have no idea to make im very confused by seening many tutorial sampel like thisone [link](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/scroll_view/create_a_horizontal_scrolling_button_list/)

Answer (score 4):

Follow my code:

```
CGFloat btnX = 80.0;
int numberOfButton = 10;
for (int i = 1 ; i <= numberOfButton; i++)
{
   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(newView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   button.tag = i;
   [button setTitle:@"Excavations" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
   [scrollview addSubView:button];
   btnX = btnX + 165.0;
}
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(btnX + 50, yourHeight);
```

Your warning says that you forgot to add method of your `UIButton`, so you need to declare method of button, such like..

```
-(void) newView:(UIButton *) sender
{
   //you can access your button by it's tag.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)createScrollViewMenu
{
  UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];

    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 100, 100)];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NameOfBtn %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        button.tag = i;
        [scrollView addSubview:button];

        x += button.frame.size.width;
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, scrollView.frame.size.height);
        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

   [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

This will create a scrollview with a height of 100, width as big as its parent, and add 10 buttons to it.
so you need to declare method of button, such like..

```
 -(void)BtnClicked:(UIButton *) sender
  {
   //you can access your button by it's tag.
 }
```